# layout_gravity does not work inside LinearLayout , android

Tags: android

I am learning android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.raju.layoutlearn1.MainActivity"
    android:background="#9cf"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the `TextView` to be in the center horizontally. But it is not working.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your LinearLayout is horizontal. Make your LinearLayout orientation vertical.